# Applying log to all elements in a list of time-series

Tags: r, list, time-series

I would like to apply the function `log` to the elements in this list:

```
list(DNK = structure(c(17.6211745719591, 16.9704417500702, 16.1549721533571
), .Tsp = c(2014, 2014.16666666667, 12), class = "ts"), NOR = structure(c(14.9003874574234, 
15.0006940004899, 12.121294393011), .Tsp = c(2014, 2014.16666666667, 
12), class = "ts"))
```

Expected result is:

```
list(DNK = structure(c(2.869101, 2.831473, 2.782228
), .Tsp = c(2014, 2014.16666666667, 12), class = "ts"), NOR = structure(c(2.701387, 
2.494964, 2.494964), .Tsp = c(2014, 2014.16666666667, 
12), class = "ts"))
```

Thanks in advance for your insights/answers!

Comment: Although this isn't hard to do is there some reason you are using such a non-standard format when this could be stored as a multivariate series: tt <- do.call("cbind", L) in which case all operations would be easier, .e.g. log(tt) ?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, you're right. Thanks for calling it. I'm preparing a dataset to use with the package BGVAR. It also accepts matrices, instead of lists. Therefore, I'll handle the data differently from now on, rather using matrices.

Comment: I didn't realize there is actually a package that uses that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and `log` the elements

```
lapply(lst1, log)
#$DNK
#         Jan      Feb      Mar
#2014 2.869101 2.831473 2.782228

#$NOR
#          Jan      Feb      Mar
#2014 2.701387 2.708096 2.494964
```

Answer (score 3):

```
example <- list(DNK = structure(c(17.6211745719591, 16.9704417500702, 16.1549721533571
), .Tsp = c(2014, 2014.16666666667, 12), class = "ts"), NOR = structure(c(14.9003874574234, 
                                                                          15.0006940004899, 12.121294393011), .Tsp = c(2014, 2014.16666666667, 
                                                                                                                       12), class = "ts"))


lapply(example, log)
```

that should solve your problem

Comment: Yes i'am sorry, i was writing while you already have posted your solution

Comment: Yes, it was almost simultaneously!